# Swift: Animation code on LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I want to **rotate an app logo on my Launch Screen** (LaunchScreen.storyboard).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755504/rotate-a-view-for-360-degrees-indefinitely-in-swift) helps me in getting the code to rotate an image. However, where can I put this code?

Since there is no class file associated with the Launch Screen, how can I acheive this?

Comment: You need to create replica of launch screen  (New View Controller) and show it right after the launch screen appears , apply animation there

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: Probably because it has been asked many times and the answer is always the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't directly do that** as the launch screen is static. Even if it's set up via a .xib or a storyboard file, it will appear as a snapshot of the initial state of that scene.

You should create a view controller with the same look as your launch screen and animate that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve that. Before `LaunchScreen.storyboard` you was putting only static images in order to be shown on launch. `LaunchScreen.storyboard` is introduced later to simplify the generation of static images.

But you can kind of workaround it. You display exactly same looking view controller just after launchscreen and run animation. But there will be a little delay.