# Why not using weak pattern in animation blocks?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I know that there are already several questions asked about `weak` in the context of animations like [Is it necessary to use unowned self in closures of UIView.animateWithDuration(…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019676/is-it-necessary-to-use-unowned-self-in-closures-of-uiview-animatewithduration) While it is obvious in the latter case, that you can omit `weak`, I have still difficulties, to see the reason, why I should not use the `weak` pattern in [Robs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227387/2691779) about a rotating view. I do not want to disturb the comments there, so I ask the question here.

The code in question is

```swift
private func createAnimation() {
     animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 4, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) { [self] in
         UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4, delay: 0) {
             UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0 / 3.0) {
                 animatedView.transform = .init(rotationAngle: .pi * 2 * 1 / 3)
             }
             ...
         }
     } completion: { [weak self] _ in
         self?.createAnimation()
     }
 }
```

Rob used the `[weak self]` in the `completion`-closure but not in the `animations`-closure, where he actually put `self` into the capture list to make his intention obvious. How can I know, that `UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator` will never put the (escaping) `animations`-closure into the created `animator`-instance-variable?

I don't think, that `UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator` actually captures the `animations`-closure, but as long as I have no idea, how `UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator` is implemented, or will be implemented in the future, how can I be sure?

Maybe this pseudo-implementation could help to explain, what I mean:

```swift
import Foundation

class UIView {
    var transform = CGFloat.zero
    static func animateKeyFrames(animations: () -> Void) {}
    static func addKeyframe(animations: () -> Void) {}
}

class UIViewPropertyAnimator {
    
    var animations: () -> Void = {}
    var completion: (() -> Void)? = {}
    
    static func runningPropertyAnimator(animations: @escaping () -> Void,
                                        completion: (() -> Void)?) -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator()
        animator.animations = animations
        animator.completion = completion
        
        return animator
    }
}

class ViewController {
    var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
    let animatedView = UIView()
    
    func viewDidLoad() {
        createAnimation()
    }
    
    func createAnimation() {
        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(animations: { [weak self] in
            UIView.animateKeyFrames(animations: {
                UIView.addKeyframe(animations: {
                    self?.animatedView.transform = .zero
                })
            })
        }, completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.animatedView.transform = .zero
        })
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

func createAndRelease() {
    let viewController = ViewController()
    viewController.viewDidLoad()
}

createAndRelease()
```

Removing `[weak self]` from the `animations` or `completion`-closure would obviously cause a retain-cycle in my pseudo-code and `deinit` would never be called.

Comment: The situation for `UIView.animate` is different from the situation for UIViewPropertyAnimator, because you might retain a UIViewPropertyAnimator.

Answer (score 1):

Closure-based animation API have two closures, the animation closure (which is called when the animation starts and is then released) and, optionally, the completion handler closure (which is called when the animation is done).

Consider:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        subview.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(subview)

        logger.debug("creating animator")
        animator = .runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 1) {
            logger.debug("animate closure called")
            subview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        } completion: { position in
            logger.debug("completion closure called")
        }
    }
}
```

That will output:

```
2021-03-31 16:08:00.384558-0700 MyApp[3837:8759577] [ViewController] creating animator
2021-03-31 16:08:00.384899-0700 MyApp[3837:8759577] [ViewController] animate closure called
2021-03-31 16:08:02.386253-0700 MyApp[3837:8759577] [ViewController] completion closure called
```

Note the timestamps in the above debugging log: The `animations` closure is called immediately after the animator is created, and well before the `completion` closure is called.

In your pseudocode example, you seem to be assuming that the animator stores and retains a reference to the `animations` closure. It does not do that (and nor should it). It runs the `animation` closure to figure out what is being animated and then releases it. It does not keep a strong reference to that closure after the animation begins.

A better pseudocode example might be:

```swift
class UIViewPropertyAnimatorMockup {
    var animations: (() -> Void)?
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    static func runningPropertyAnimator(animations: @escaping () -> Void, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> UIViewPropertyAnimatorMockup {
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimatorMockup()
        animator.animations = animations
        animator.completion = completion
        animator.run()
        return animator
    }

    func run() {
        beginTransaction()
        animations?()
        endTransaction()

        animations = nil         // release that `animations` reference now that we're done with it
    }

    func didFinishAnimations() {
        completion?()
        completion = nil         // release that `completion` reference now that we're done with it
    }
}
```

This obviously is not precisely what `UIViewPropertyAnimator` is doing, but the idea to understand is that as soon as it calls the closure and is done with it, it releases its strong reference. This applies to both the `animations` closure and the `completion` closure (the latter obviously being released a bit later).

---

As an aside, this is a good pattern to follow in one’s own closure-based code. If you save a closure in some property, make sure to (a) make it optional; and (b) `nil` that property as soon as you are done with the closure.

This is a defensive programming pattern, mitigating damage if an application developer accidentally introduces a strong reference that they should not have.

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks much more realistic of course and all tests indicate that `UIViewPropertyAnimator` will not keep the `animations`-closure alive. But can I really be 100 percent sure about it? `UIViewPropertyAnimator` seems like a black box to me. I am am neither assuming that the animator stores and retains a  reference of the `animations`-closure nor that he will never ever do it. My thought is: I simply don't know it for sure. The pure possibility, that `UIViewPropertyAnimator` **could** keep a reference of the `animations`-closure would motivate me to use `weak`.

Comment: An `animations` closure obviously _must_ be called before the animation starts and it seems like a curious concern to assume that the property animator might secretly keep a reference to it beyond that, especially when you've demonstrated empirically that it doesn't. But I guess that in the lack of any formal assurances to this end, one certainly could add `[weak self]` pattern if one wanted. It seems unwarranted to my eye, only adding syntactic noise and (admittedly negligible) overhead, but to each his own. (But I wouldn't advise changing other people answers to add `[weak self]`; lol.)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain your opinion! And sorry: I did not intend to offend you by editing your (very helpful) answer! This was my lack of experience: It looked just like an accidental missing `weak`, so I asked you in the comments and after a few days I thought: "Sure, just an accidental missing" so I just added it too soon.

Comment: No offense taken!